# VBA Macro timer as a function() instead of a sub() - losing the first variable

Tags: excel, vba, function, timer, public

I'm attempting to clean up some recorded macros, and would like to test if my optimizations are actually speeding this up.  I want to add a macro timer to test, but ideally I'd add it as a set of two public function()s, rather than inside the code.

THe problem arises when the code fails to recall the time1 variable. I assume that there's a way to get the first time as a constant, but I'm not sure how

when I attempt to change the "dim timer1" to "const timer1" I get an error that I've been unable to resolve.  Am I going about this the wrong way?  Do I need to abandon the idea of having this as functions?

```
 Sub timertestSub()

    Dim time1 As Double
    Dim time2 As Double
    Dim totaltime As String

    time1 = Timer()

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

    time2 = Timer()

    totaltime = Format((time2 - time1) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

    MsgBox "code ran in " & totaltime
    End Sub

Function startTime()

    Dim time1 As Double

    time1 = Timer()

    Debug.Print "time1 is: " & time1

    End Function


Function endTIme()

    Dim time2 As Double
    Dim totaltime As Double

    'confirm orig variable
    Debug.Print "time1 recalled as: " & time1

    time2 = Timer()
    Debug.Print "time2 is: " & time2

    totaltime = (time2 - time1)
    Debug.Print "TotalTime is: " & totaltime

    MsgBox "code ran in " & Format(totaltime / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

    End Function

Sub timertestFunction()

    Call startTime


    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

    Call endTIme

    End Sub
```

the sub timertestSub() works as expected, but the sub timertestFunction() loses the time1 variable; so the final output is just the current time

Trying to chance the code from dim timer1 as double to const timer1 as double is also giving me errors.

Comment: Define it as a `Static` variable.

Comment: You are not passing anything to, or returning anything from your functions.

Comment: that's a great idea, it's giving the same results though.  Like the static variable is also being forgotten by the end of the first function

Comment: I just ran your code and had no issues - however "Trying to chance the code from `dim timer1 as double` to `const timer1 as double`" implies a spelling error in your original code (not the code presented here) which `Option Explicit` at the top of the module will bring to the surface.

Comment: @chrisneilsen can you explain a little more what you mean by that?

Comment: @AJD when you ran the sub timertestFunction() you got 10 seconds?  not the current time?  Because every time I run it, I'm only getting the current time, or basically timer2 - null  Re: option explicit, I actually turned that off because it seemed to be preventing the sub timertestfunction() from correctly identifying timer1; I presume for the same reason that it runs as empty; I'm just not sure what the workaround is

Comment: I actually got 9 seconds, but that might have been due to a rounding error. But yes, the result was elapsed time, not current time. So the code you are running must be different from the code you presented here.

Comment: just to be clear, there are two subs in the code above; the first sub runs as expected, and is really there for me to test my assumptions about the two functions; and the second sub is an attempt to run the two functions.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to run the code by simply moving the "dim time1 as double" ABOVE all the functions as "public time1 as double"  which allowed the function endtime to reference it; and also resolved the option explicit error.  in the end it wasn't that the time1 value was being lost, it was that because it was not a public variable, it couldn't be referenced properly by the other functions/subs

```
public time1 as double

Function startTime()

    time1 = Timer()

    Debug.Print "time1 is: " & time1

    End Function


Function endTIme()

    Dim time2 As Double
    Dim totaltime As Double

    'confirm orig variable
    Debug.Print "time1 recalled as: " & time1

    time2 = Timer()
    Debug.Print "time2 is: " & time2

    totaltime = (time2 - time1)
    Debug.Print "TotalTime is: " & totaltime

    MsgBox "code ran in " & Format(totaltime / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

    End Function

Sub timertestFunction()

    Call startTime


    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

    Call endTIme

    End Sub
```